# Include c++ project in another c++ project from different solution in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I have 2 c++ projects in different solutions. When I built the project B solution's it generated a .dll, .exp, .exe, and .lib files.

How I have to reference the project B in the project A?. I've tried rigth click -> add -> reference -> B.dll.

But it shows me a window error with the following message:

could not add a reference to B.dll for one of the following reasons:

- Targets a higher version of the .NET Framework
- Not a .NET assembly
- Not a registered ActiveX control

I've never worked with visual studio,I'm a little bit lost

Thank you and sorry for my english

Comment: You don't include projects. You could `#include` header files (and link some library). Please show some [MCVE] in your question, and give the *exact* error messages.

Comment: BTW, did you consider using [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) instead ?